# ViewModel object needed in 2 projects Core and Web - Circular Dependancies

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC application that consists of 3 projects Core, Repository & Web.

References are as follows:

- Core references Repository
- Web references Core

My ViewModels sit in the Web project, which are being used by controllers.

In the Core project I have an email class that I want to recieve the bound ViewModel object as a parameter (to send an HTML email of the record).

The problem is that I can't use that object as a parameter in the email method as it will create a circular dependency.

Any ideas how I can have that object in 2 projects at once??

Comment: do you have to use view models in core? can they not be converted to domain objects and these passed instead?

Comment: Core shouldn't have any dependency on view models, those are application-level objects.  If there's a *business model* representing this structure then that would go in Core and the application layer would reference that.

Comment: I am converting them to domain models for context actions but I would like to use the attributes attached to the ViewModel as these are the only way I can reproduce the 'DisplayName' values. I basically want the email to have Label, Field for each item in the ViewModel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the view model is holding domain information, which it shouldn't be doing.  Specifically, it represents a structure of data which belongs in Core because Core has functionality that needs it.

Two main approaches to this are:

1. Create a model in Core and the view model can have that model as a property.
2. Create a model in Core and the view model can replicate its structure.  (Which would likely involve conversion methods between the two at some point.)

In either case, if you have a model that belongs in core then build it there.

What is that model?  I really can't know for sure based on the description.  For now I'm going to call it an `EmailTemplate`.  In that case it sounds like you have this:

```
Core Assembly
    Email Object
        Send Method (View Model parameter)

Web Assembly
    View Model Object
        properties
```

Instead, you'd want this:

```
Core Assembly
    Email Object
        Send Method (Email Template parameter)
    Email Template Object

Web Assembly
    View Model Object
        Email Template property
```

In fact, you *might* not even need a view model at all and just bind the view to the domain object.  But that's really tough to say without knowing more.

As you're discovering, dependencies should only ever point *inward* to the domain core.  (In fact, the Repository references are also backwards, but that's outside the scope of the question.)  Either the functionality and the structures to support it belong in Core, or the functionality itself belongs in Web.  The structure of the domain in the question is a little vague so sorry if this is light on details, but the principle is the same.

Comment: You nailed my current situation. The reason I want the ViewModel is that the annotations for DisplayName and property values are already bout to that object. The email method I want to recieve the ViewModel and output it into the body of an email EXACTLY how it is displayed in the view. Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 2):

Rethink your architecture. Your `Core` project shouldn't know ANYTHING about Web project either way... Even if it was possible (which it is not), it would still lead to tight coupling which you should be trying to prevent by using multiple projects.

If you need to pass anything to the Core function, it should be something that Core understands.. Either some custom object or even simple string or other data type.

Answer (score 2):

In the Web project you need to implement a way to convert the ViewModel Email Class to the Core Email Class.  You could do this with a mapper (like AutoMapper) or write your own conversion function in the ViewModel. After you have done the conversion you then pass the Core Email object.

Comment: So you would create a new Model in the Core project and map the ViewModel to that? Difficult to swallow when the exact object already exists, all I want to do is loop through it and output the values into an email....

Answer (score 1):

Your email class shouldn't be referencing back to a `ViewModel`. A `ViewModel` is for the `View` to consume.

I would map the values of your viewmodel back to a model and operate on the model (and your model should be colocated with the dataservice that saves the information). For this you could use Automapper or write your own mapping layer.